# list linked last node to be the first

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

modify the code so that when entering the nodes of the list, the last node becomes the first, the first node becomes the second.

```
package nodos;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
*
* @author x2010s
*/
public class Nodos {
public String nombre;

public Nodos nodosiguiente;
public Nodos nodosanterior;
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   /* enter the number of nodes to be created */   
    Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de nodos a ingresar");
    int n,contador=0;
    n=leer.nextInt();

    /* the  data of the node is entered */
    for (int i =1; i <= n; i++){
        Nodos nodo = new Nodos();
        System.out.print("ingrese la nombre ");
        nodo.nombre=leer.next();

        /* the node is created  */  
        if(contador==0){
            nodo.nodosiguiente = null;
            contador ++;
        } else {
            nodo.nodosiguiente = nodo;
            contador ++;
        }    

        /* place the last created node first */
        if (contador == n){
            nodo.nodosiguiente=nodo;
        }
        nodo.nodosanterior = null;
        for ( i =1; i<contador; i++){
            nodo.nodosanterior=nodo;
            nodo.nodosiguiente=null;
        }

        /* place the last created node first */
        for ( i =1; i <= n; i++){
            System.out.println("nombre " +nodo.nombre+ "\n");
            System.out.println("apuntador " +nodo.nodosiguiente + "\n");    
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

when I enter the amount of 3 nodes, only asks me once the data, when it prints the only node it prints it three times.

Comment: Don't use the same loop variable in nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could understand, your outer loop exits after one iteration since the inner loops use the same variable and its value violates the condition after one complete iteration of the outer loop.

You should use different local variables within the `for` loop scope specifically when they are nested in your case :-

```
for (int j = 1; j < contador; j++){
    nodo.nodosanterior=nodo;
    nodo.nodosiguiente=null;
}

for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++){
    System.out.println("nombre " +nodo.nombre);
    System.out.println("apuntador " +nodo.nodosiguiente);    
}
```